# Which webserver is WebLogic using?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

At my company we are using Application Server , namely Oracle WebLogic.

So I created a project for our REST API . So I get out a war File.

Unfortunately I was not able to find out which kind of webserver is handling this war file.
What webserver could be possible. I was googling and most application server are using tomcat or jetty.
I do not know about WebLogic though. Also I could not find any information about this.

Comment: Weblogic is a full J2EE compliant application server. It embeds its own web server to handle http requests. What kind of information do you need about WebLogic ?

Comment: Interesting. WebLogic has its own Webserver. That is different to other Application Servers. Why is WebLogic using its own webserver and not let's say TomCat or Jetty :)

Comment: Tomcat and Jetty embeded also a web server. This kind of component is required to handle http requests.

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic Server can be used as the primary Web server for advanced Web-enabled applications. A J2EE Web application is a collection of HTML or XML pages, JavaServer Pages, servlets, Java classes, applets, images, multimedia files, and other types of files. And also, We can use the other web servers like Tomcat, Apache, IIS ..etc.

A static web server consists of a computer (hardware) with an HTTP server (software). We call it "static" because the server sends its hosted files as-is to your browser.

A dynamic web server consists of a static web server plus extra software, most commonly an application server and a database. We call it "dynamic" because the application server updates the hosted files before sending content to your browser via the HTTP server.

You can use apache as a web server and the Apache Web server provides a full range of Web server features, including CGI, SSL, and virtual domains. Apache also supports plug-in modules for extensibility. Apache is free software, distributed by the Apache Software Foundation that promotes various free and open source advanced Web technologies.

Please follow the below links for how to use weblogic as a web server [1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/web_server.html) and how to use Apache (open source) as a web server.[2](http://weblogicexpert.weebly.com/configuring-apache-web-server-with-weblogic.html)